# How to call 'ALTER SESSION' inside a sqlplus call in shell script

Tags: shell-script, sqlplus

I have a requirement to call `ALTER SESSION` command within an existing shell script's SQLPlus block.

When I tried to call it as `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set optimizer_dynamic_sampling=5'`, it didn't work: I get the ORA error `ERROR at line 1: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`.

What am I doing wrong here ? Below is the snippet.

```
 sqlplus -s << EOS
                            $CONNECT_STRING
                            Whenever SqlError Exit 45;
                            **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set optimizer_dynamic_sampling=5';** 
                            exec PACKAGE.PROCEDURE
 EOS
```

TIA

Comment: Please use the `{}` formatting tool to format your code as code. Also, please show where you want the "ALTER SESSION" to show up.

Comment: Hi Jeff,Thanks - I made the changes as suggested.

Comment: What problem are you facing, exactly? Are you trying to use a command to edit that text into another script file? Or when you use the updated script you get a SQL error?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - This is just a part of the entire shell script, this is the part where the shell script is calling the Oracle Database to execute the package. The error that I face while running the shell script is an ORA error        
 "ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
"

Comment: What are those `**` pairs doing in your code? Are they really there - in which case I'm sure they're errors - or are they left-over attempts to format in bold instead of code?

Comment: Does `$CONNECT_STRING` have a valid value? You don't mention it anywhere so we'd have to guess that this isn't the cause of your problem.

Comment: If you type those ORACLE commands into an interactive SQLPlus sesssion do they work?

Comment: Finally (for now), if you replace `sqlplus -s` with `cat` do you see what you expect to see?

Comment: Thank You for the suggestions everyone. The issue was rectified with a simple dos2unix conversion of the file :(